# Dynamic Gnuplot graphs

Tags: file, dynamic, graph, gnuplot

I have a continuously updating data file. I want to use Gnuplot to dynamically plot the updating data file, possibly using a window of the last 100 data points.

Is it possible? If so, some pointers are appreciated.

Comment: What OS would this be running on?  What version of Gnuplot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way you can accomplish it with Gnuplot and some bash scripting:

```
# An updating data file
while :; do echo $((RANDOM%100)); sleep .1; done > datafile
```

Initialize Gnuplot with a plot command, and let the other updates come from replot:

```
(
  echo "plot [0:100] [0:100] '< tail -n100 datafile' with lines";
  while :; do sleep .4; echo replot; done
) | gnuplot -persist
```

This makes Gnuplot evaluate `tail -n100 datafile` every .4 seconds and use the result as the data set. The tail command returns the last 100 lines of `datafile`.

Comment: There is at least two options in `gnuplot` , for `plot` command: `skip` and `every`. So your introduction is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

## Dynamic plot using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and [gnuplot](/questions/tagged/gnuplot):

### Only 100 last values

#### By `gnuplot` script (quick demo)

Simply try this two commands:

.1 populate dynamic datafile in background

```
ping -i.2 google.com |
    sed -ue 's/.*seq=\([0-9]\+\) .*time=\([0-9.]\+\) .*/\1 \2/p;d' > file.dat &
```

.2 run gnuplot with inline script (feel free replacing `MAX=40` by `MAX=100` ;-)

```
MAX=40
gnuplot -e "while(1){pause 0.1;stats 'file.dat' u 0 nooutput;
    lPnts=STATS_records<$MAX?0: STATS_records-$MAX;
    plot 'file.dat' using 1:2 skip lPnts title 'google' w st  }"
```

You have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to quit gnuplot, **then** `kill %%` to stop running `ping`.

#### By [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script

There is a little [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script maintaining data file keeping only last 100 values. This simply use a counter, then delete 1st value in data file once counter reach limit:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare TMPDIR=/tmp DEST=${1:-google.com} DELAY=${2:-.25} MAXDATA=100
[ -d /dev/shm ] && [ -w /dev/shm ] && TMPDIR=/dev/shm
read -r TMPDAT < <(mktemp -p "$TMPDIR" --suffix .dat plot-XXXXXXXXXX)

exec {PFD}> >(exec gnuplot)
closExit() { exec {PFD}>&- ; [ -f "$TMPDAT" ] && rm "$TMPDAT" ; exit ;}
trap closExit 0 1 2 3 6 15

getDatas() {
    read -r data < <(
        ping -c 1 -n "$DEST" 2>&1 |
            sed -u 's/^64.*time=\([0-9.]\+\) .*$/\1/p;d'
    )
    now=$EPOCHREALTIME
    printf '%.6f %s\n' >>"$TMPDAT" "$now" "$data"
    (( cnt++ > MAXDATA )) && sed -e 1d -i "$TMPDAT"
    printf ' %8d %(%a %b %d %T)T.%s %s\n' \
            "$cnt" "${now%.*}" "${now#*.}" "$data"
}
getDatas

echo >&$PFD "set term wxt noraise persist title 'Ping $DEST';"
echo >&$PFD "set xdata time;"
echo >&$PFD "set timefmt '%s';"

while ! read -rsn 1 -t "$DELAY" ;do
    getDatas
    echo >&$PFD "plot '$TMPDAT' using 1:2 with line title 'ping $DEST';"
done
```

Sample run (accelerated approx x15 animated gif):

[image: Ping graph sample]

#### Multiprocess demo script

I wrote a [multiping bash script](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/multiping.sh.txt) that could dynamically run gnuplot (and ping together as many background tasks).

In this script, there was no *limit to Nth last values*, but this script show how to read datas from many different streams, keeping *STDIO* for interactivity and addressing another stream for ordering *plot upgrade* to `gnuplot` sub-process.

You could run:

```
multiping.sh -pci .3 www.google.com www.stackexchange.com
```

The goal there was to create **interactive** [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script managing different sub-process, for input and/or output.

***Commands***

While running, you could interact with:

- <kbd>q</kbd> to quit (close all FD, terminate all subprocess)
- <kbd>p</kbd> to start plotting using new `gnuplot` subprocess
- <kbd>s</kbd> to stop plotting
- <kbd>r</kbd> to reset console terminal
- <kbd>h</kbd> to print header line in console terminal

***Usage***

Command line `-h` switch will show then help:

```
Usage: multiping.sh [-[cdhp]] [-i N] <host or ip> [host or ip] [host or ip]...
  Options:
    -c      colors (red for no answer, green for higher "seq" number)
    -d      Debug this (by opening 2 xterm windows... look at script)
    -h      help (print this)
    -iN     Interval for ping command (min 0.2 in user mode)
    -p      Plot dynamically (require gnuplot)
    All following argument will be "target" for "ping" command.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *gnuplot-only* version without the need of an external script.
It also works with gnuplot 4.6.0 (the version at the time of OP's question).
Since I'm lacking a data source which is updated constantly, I create the datafile within gnuplot itself. If you have your file updated externally by another program skip the lines marked with `# *skip`.

The plotting is running in a `while` loop (check `help while`) and can be stopped by pressing `x`, check `help bind`. Adjust the time delay between to plots by setting an appropriate number (check `help pause`).

**Code:**

```
### dynamic plotting of last 20 points
reset

FILE = 'Test.dat'

bind x 'stop = 1'   # stop loop via pressing x
stop = 0

N = 20
set yrange [0:3]

set print FILE          # *skip these lines if your file is updated by another program
set print FILE append   # *skip
idx = 0                 # *skip

while (!stop) {

    print sprintf("%g %g",idx=idx+1,sin(idx/3.)+rand(0)*0.5+1)   # *skip
    
    pause 0.05       # pause in seconds
    stats [*:*][*:*] FILE u 0 nooutput
    LastN = STATS_records<N ? 0 : STATS_records-N
    
    plot FILE u 1:2 every ::LastN w lp pt 7
}
set print               # *skip
### end of code
```

**Result:** (Screen capture using ScreenToGif from a wxt terminal on gnuplot 4.6.0)

[image]